# Xubuntu 19.10: Chkrootkit; tty's of user processes not found

Tags: bash, security, hardware, tty, malware

Every time I've done a fresh install of any Linux system, whether it be any Ubuntu variation, Solus, Debian (installing overnight in Rescue Mode) I seem to run into errors and running **Chkrootkit** always at some point on the day of installing (most the time on the first scan) shows up at the end saying **"The tty of the following user process(es) were not found"** :

```
Checking `chkutmp'...                                        The tty of the following user process(es) were not found
 in /var/run/utmp !
! RUID          PID TTY    CMD
! user+     2123 pts/0  bash
! root         2511 pts/0  /bin/sh /usr/sbin/chkrootkit
! root         3187 pts/0  ./chkutmp
! root         3189 pts/0  ps axk tty,ruser,args -o tty,pid,ruser,args
! root         3188 pts/0  sh -c ps axk "tty,ruser,args" -o "tty,pid,ruser,args"
! root         2510 pts/0  sudo chkrootkit
chkutmp: nothing deleted
Checking `OSX_RSPLUG'...                                    not tested
```

I've tried numerous things to fix this but has only seemed to mitigate the issue without fully rectifying it, or on a couple of occasions so far had no tty issues detected temporarily before it resurfaces the same day from a clean install after installing simple packages from the terminal using the apt & snap stores, such as Chromium, VLC, Gparted, Synaptic.

I've booted into a shell environment with **Debian** in **Rescue Mode** to fully wipe and overwrite my Hard Drive with random data using the commands:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdb
```

also using the following commands to try and reset my RAM getting rid of all Swap & Loop data using:

```
sync; echo 1 /proc/syn/vm/drop_caches
sync; echo 2 /proc/syn/vm/drop_caches
sync; echo 3 /proc/syn/vm/drop_caches
echo 3 > proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && swapoff -a && swapon -a && printf '\n%s\n' 'Ram-cache and Swap Cleared'
```

I've installed and ran **Hardware Probe** from the Snap Store, below are the results:

https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=11cbce30b4

Some results there don't seem to make any sense, namely the fact that it looks to me as though it's detecting that there's an SD card plugged in when there isn't, nor any other removable media at the time of any of the probes I've performed.

Also the fact that at the bottom of the page under **Wireless** simply says: '**1. Rfkill**' and nothing else listed and has no link for further info like all probes from other users I've looked at so far, even probes for the same **Toshiba Satellite C660** model range as my laptop, with some other differences that appear a bit strange, *although* those other users don't appear to have my exact laptop unfortunately, being the Toshiba C660D by the looks of it, whereas mine is the **C660-2EL**. I have no idea what to make of that result under 'Wireless' personally other than it's different to most, if not all probes from other users.

Next, whenever I do a clean install of **Windows** with **no other** OS installed, a **Removable Device** appears in **Device Manager** which disappears as though it were removed when I right-click and select to **uninstall** the device, but simply returns after rebooting.

I can't be sure but I think the SD card **Hardware Probe** looks to be detecting on my Linux systems is that same *mysterious* Removable Device re-appearing in **Windows'** Device Manager, with nothing left in the disk drive or any removable devices connected **at all**.

It may be some kind of **mounted memory volume/block device** somewhere which would explain why a '**/dev/sdb**' always shows up on my Hard Drive from nowhere which is separate from my primary partition where I install my Linux OS' in '**/dev/sda**'.

Much like the extra Linux partition automatically appearing upon installing from multiple different USB drives/DVD's, an extra **inaccessible** '**Disk**' with a supposed **volume of 0 Mb** also shows up in Windows' **Command Prompt** after running the **diskpart** command, despite running as Admin or trying to access through recovery mode by pressing F8 at the BIOS menu or loading through a bootable drive.

I must mention that I've not once done anything to modify my laptop in any way since I started using it around October, 2012. To reiterate, the model is a **Toshiba C660-2EL**, made in **2012** and the serial number is: **XB018145K**. I've tried flashing the BIOS in Windows but to no avail, every method simply fails for some reason even though I'm sure I'm doing everything right. The BIOS shows up as TOSHIBA on the Linux Harware Monitor but it's actually **Phoenix** and always has been as far as I'm concerned, though the same thing is displayed for other Toshiba laptop probes so I think that's just normal.

Below is my full last Chkrootkit scan:

```
ROOTDIR is `/'
Checking `amd'...                                           not found
Checking `basename'...                                      not infected
Checking `biff'...                                          not found
Checking `chfn'...                                          not infected
Checking `chsh'...                                          not infected
Checking `cron'...                                          not infected
Checking `crontab'...                                       not infected
Checking `date'...                                          not infected
Checking `du'...                                            not infected
Checking `dirname'...                                       not infected
Checking `echo'...                                          not infected
Checking `egrep'...                                         not infected
Checking `env'...                                           not infected
Checking `find'...                                          not infected
Checking `fingerd'...                                       not found
Checking `gpm'...                                           not found
Checking `grep'...                                          not infected
Checking `hdparm'...                                        not infected
Checking `su'...                                            not infected
Checking `ifconfig'...                                      not infected
Checking `inetd'...                                         not infected
Checking `inetdconf'...                                     not found
Checking `identd'...                                        not found
Checking `init'...                                          not infected
Checking `killall'...                                       not infected
Checking `ldsopreload'...                                   not infected
Checking `login'...                                         not infected
Checking `ls'...                                            not infected
Checking `lsof'...                                          not infected
Checking `mail'...                                          not found
Checking `mingetty'...                                      not found
Checking `netstat'...                                       not infected
Checking `named'...                                         not found
Checking `passwd'...                                        not infected
Checking `pidof'...                                         not infected
Checking `pop2'...                                          not found
Checking `pop3'...                                          not found
Checking `ps'...                                            not infected
Checking `pstree'...                                        not infected
Checking `rpcinfo'...                                       not found
Checking `rlogind'...                                       not found
Checking `rshd'...                                          not found
Checking `slogin'...                                        not infected
Checking `sendmail'...                                      not found
Checking `sshd'...                                          not found
Checking `syslogd'...                                       not tested
Checking `tar'...                                           not infected
Checking `tcpd'...                                          not found
Checking `tcpdump'...                                       not infected
Checking `top'...                                           not infected
Checking `telnetd'...                                       not found
Checking `timed'...                                         not found
Checking `traceroute'...                                    not found
Checking `vdir'...                                          not infected
Checking `w'...                                             not infected
Checking `write'...                                         not infected
Checking `aliens'...                                        no suspect files
Searching for sniffer's logs, it may take a while...        nothing found
Searching for rootkit HiDrootkit's default files...         nothing found
Searching for rootkit t0rn's default files...               nothing found
Searching for t0rn's v8 defaults...                         nothing found
Searching for rootkit Lion's default files...               nothing found
Searching for rootkit RSHA's default files...               nothing found
Searching for rootkit RH-Sharpe's default files...          nothing found
Searching for Ambient's rootkit (ark) default files and dirs... nothing found
Searching for suspicious files and dirs, it may take a while... The following suspicious files and directories were found:  
/usr/lib/debug/.build-id /usr/lib/libreoffice/share/fonts/truetype/.uuid /usr/lib/modules/5.3.0-19-generic/vdso/.build-id /usr/lib/modules/5.3.0-18-generic/vdso/.build-id /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/uic/widget-plugins/.noinit
/usr/lib/debug/.build-id /usr/lib/modules/5.3.0-19-generic/vdso/.build-id /usr/lib/modules/5.3.0-18-generic/vdso/.build-id
Searching for LPD Worm files and dirs...                    nothing found
Searching for Ramen Worm files and dirs...                  nothing found
Searching for Maniac files and dirs...                      nothing found
Searching for RK17 files and dirs...                        nothing found
Searching for Ducoci rootkit...                             nothing found
Searching for Adore Worm...                                 nothing found
Searching for ShitC Worm...                                 nothing found
Searching for Omega Worm...                                 nothing found
Searching for Sadmind/IIS Worm...                           nothing found
Searching for MonKit...                                     nothing found
Searching for Showtee...                                    nothing found
Searching for OpticKit...                                   nothing found
Searching for T.R.K...                                      nothing found
Searching for Mithra...                                     nothing found
Searching for LOC rootkit...                                nothing found
Searching for Romanian rootkit...                           nothing found
Searching for Suckit rootkit...                             nothing found
Searching for Volc rootkit...                               nothing found
Searching for Gold2 rootkit...                              nothing found
Searching for TC2 Worm default files and dirs...            nothing found
Searching for Anonoying rootkit default files and dirs...   nothing found
Searching for ZK rootkit default files and dirs...          nothing found
Searching for ShKit rootkit default files and dirs...       nothing found
Searching for AjaKit rootkit default files and dirs...      nothing found
Searching for zaRwT rootkit default files and dirs...       nothing found
Searching for Madalin rootkit default files...              nothing found
Searching for Fu rootkit default files...                   nothing found
Searching for ESRK rootkit default files...                 nothing found
Searching for rootedoor...                                  nothing found
Searching for ENYELKM rootkit default files...              nothing found
Searching for common ssh-scanners default files...          nothing found
Searching for Linux/Ebury - Operation Windigo ssh...        not tested
Searching for 64-bit Linux Rootkit ...                      nothing found
Searching for 64-bit Linux Rootkit modules...               nothing found
Searching for Mumblehard Linux ...                          nothing found
Searching for Backdoor.Linux.Mokes.a ...                    nothing found
Searching for Malicious TinyDNS ...                         nothing found
Searching for Linux.Xor.DDoS ...                            nothing found
Searching for Linux.Proxy.1.0 ...                           nothing found
Searching for suspect PHP files...                          nothing found
Searching for anomalies in shell history files...           nothing found
Checking `asp'...                                           not infected
Checking `bindshell'...                                     not infected
Checking `lkm'...                                           chkproc: nothing detected
chkdirs: nothing detected
Checking `rexedcs'...                                       not found
Checking `sniffer'...                                       lo: not promisc and no packet sniffer sockets
wlp6s0: PACKET SNIFFER(/usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant[951], /usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant[951])
tun0: not promisc and no packet sniffer sockets
Checking `w55808'...                                        not infected
Checking `wted'...                                          chkwtmp: nothing deleted
Checking `scalper'...                                       not infected
Checking `slapper'...                                       not infected
Checking `z2'...                                            user jacidious deleted or never logged from lastlog!
Checking `chkutmp'...                                        The tty of the following user process(es) were not found
 in /var/run/utmp !
! RUID          PID TTY    CMD
! user+     2123 pts/0  bash
! root         2511 pts/0  /bin/sh /usr/sbin/chkrootkit
! root         3187 pts/0  ./chkutmp
! root         3189 pts/0  ps axk tty,ruser,args -o tty,pid,ruser,args
! root         3188 pts/0  sh -c ps axk "tty,ruser,args" -o "tty,pid,ruser,args"
! root         2510 pts/0  sudo chkrootkit
```

Comment: Make a probe by native package https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Hardware_probe to get more hardware info.

Also click on the device row to find laptops with the same Wireless device.